# How to know if the program is runnig from USB or Fixed HDD?

Tags: vb.net, path, usb, filepath

Here is my problem: I have make a program for myself that is managing the TV seria that I am watching. Yesterday I got the idea to add the possibility to copy all the seriafolder and the .exe file of the program to USB, so I can take it with me if i need it. This is solved. Now I need that the program recognize if it was started from an USB Key or from HDD. Considerate these points:

1. When is on an HDD the program is actually search for a locator file, that automatically will put the path wrote inside, to the textbox1.text. This should not be happen on USB, because it's a fixed path (SerVision\Telefilm) and only the drive letter could change. I was thinking to solve checking on the run if the textbox1.text is empty (because it can be the first time running from HDD or running from USB) in this way im my form1_load:

   ```
   Dim myd As DriveInfo
   For Each myd In DriveInfo.GetDrives
       If TextBox1.Text = "" AndAlso myd.IsReady AndAlso myd.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
           Dim USBPath As String = myd.Name + "Servision\Telefilm\"
           Call AggiornaListView()
       End If
       If TextBox1.Text = "" AndAlso myd.IsReady AndAlso myd.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Fixed Then
           Dim ROAD As String = Application.StartupPath()
           TextBox1.Text = ROAD
       End If
   Next
   ```

Butin Textbox1, I always got only the drive name (from USB in mycase is G:) instead to have the full path (G.\SerVision\Telefilm).

2. This is my full form1_load:

   ```
   Try 
       ListBox1.Enabled = False          
       TextBox3.Visible = False
       Button3.Enabled = False
       Dim Path As String = Application.StartupPath() + "\SVlocator.loc"

       If File.Exists(Path) = False Then

           Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Path)

           sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
           sw.Close()


           Call AggiornaListView()
       Else

           Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Path)

           'This allows you to do one Read operation.

           TextBox1.Text = (sr.ReadToEnd())
           sr.Close()


       End If


       Dim myd As DriveInfo

       For Each myd In DriveInfo.GetDrives
           If TextBox1.Text = "" AndAlso myd.IsReady AndAlso myd.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
               Dim USBPath As String = myd.Name + "Servision\Telefilm\"
               Call AggiornaListView()
           End If
           If TextBox1.Text = "" AndAlso myd.IsReady AndAlso myd.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Fixed Then
               Dim ROAD As String = Application.StartupPath()
               TextBox1.Text = ROAD
           End If
       Next


       Call AggiornaListView()

   Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
   End Try
   ```
3. I've also tried to change it in this way:

   ```
   Try 
       ListBox1.Enabled = False
       TextBox3.Visible = False
       Button3.Enabled = False

       Dim Path As String = Application.StartupPath() + "\SVlocator.loc"

       If File.Exists(Path) = False Then

           Dim myd As DriveInfo

           For Each myd In DriveInfo.GetDrives
               If TextBox1.Text = "" AndAlso myd.IsReady AndAlso myd.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
                   Dim USBPath As String = myd.Name + "Servision\Telefilm\"
                   Call AggiornaListView()
               End If
           Next
           If TextBox1.Text = "" AndAlso myd.IsReady AndAlso myd.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Fixed Then
                   Dim ROAD As String = Application.StartupPath()
               TextBox1.Text = ROAD
               Call AggiornaListView()
           End If



           Call AggiornaListView()

           Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Path)

           sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
           sw.Close()


           Call AggiornaListView()
       Else

           Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Path)

           'This allows you to do one Read operation.

           TextBox1.Text = (sr.ReadToEnd())
           sr.Close()


       End If


       Call AggiornaListView()

   Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
   End Try
   ```

Can someone please put me on the good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a really easy way to do this with [DriveInfo.DriveType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

First just: `Imports System.IO`

Then using the function below you can just do:

```
Dim MyDrive As String = Path.GetPathRoot(Application.StartupPath)

If GetDriveType(MyDrive) = DriveType.Removable Then
    'Program running from USB
Else
    'Program running from PC
End If
```

Then just add the function bellow

```
Public Function GetDriveType(ByVal Drive As String) As DriveType
    Dim MyDrive As New DriveInfo(Drive)
    Return MyDrive.DriveType
End Function
```

Comment: Nice, but I have two notes: **A)** `Exit Select` isn't necessary since there is no code after it in the same case _**AND**_ because `Return` will already exit the entire function. **B)** Your whole `Select Case` statement can be shortened to: `Return driveType`.

Comment: `Exit Select` is used only if you want to exit the current case early (for instance if you check a condition and want to skip the rest of the code in the case).

Comment: @VisualVincent That's true since he doesn't need check and handle every type we can just return **DriveType** like the edited code right?

Comment: Yeah, that's enough. The function is only responsible for getting the type. Handling each type should be done outside it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was not expecting to have so fast answers. Thanks again. In the meanwhile I was experimenting again and i found a workaround. I decided for the application to create on the start a directory called "Telefilm" under the current directory and put this path on textbox1. text if is empty. In any case, i also have a folderbrowser to choose the directory I prefere...

Comment: This is the little code i have implemented in the very beginning of my form_load before of the Try: `If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            Dim destinationpath As String = FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\Telefilm"
            If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationpath) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationpath)
            End If
            TextBox1.Text = destinationpath
        End If`

Comment: @RobertoN No problem if you decide to use the solution documented here make sure to mark it as answer.